# Adjoint of the Hodge de Rham star operator under the integral pairing

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ of dimension $n$, the Hodge star operator $\star: \Omega^k(M) \to \Omega^{n-k}(M)$ is defined. What is the (formal) adjoint of $\star$ under the integration pairing? That is, I'm looking for an operator $\sharp$ that assigns to a $(n-k)$-dimensional submanifold $S$ a $k$-dimensional (singular?) submanifold $\sharp S$ in such a way that 
$$
\int_S \star \, \alpha = \int_{\sharp S} \alpha
$$
holds for all $\alpha \in \Omega^k(M)$.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_(mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_(mathematics))

Comment: The answer is built-in your question.

Comment: Sure, I can always view the last equality as a defining equation for a current. My question is rather if this current has a geometric interpretation or can be constructed by other means. My inspiration came from the fact that the exterior differential has the boundary operator as the adjoint and I was hoping for something comparable for the Hodge operator, perhaps using some kind of flow constructed with the help of the Riemannian metric.